# Laravel Polymorphic Database Seeder Factory

Tags: laravel-5, polymorphic-associations, laravel-seeding

How can I create a database seeder factory for the following configuration?

**User**

```
// create_users_table.php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    ...
}

// User.php
public function notes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Note', 'noteable');
}
```

**Complex**

```
// create_complex_table.php
Schema::create('complex', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    ...
}

// Complex.php
public function notes()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Note', 'noteable');
}
```

**Notes**

```
// create_notes_table.php
Schema::create('notes', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('noteable_id');
    $table->string('noteable_type');
    ...
}

// Note.php
public function noteable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

I am struggling to see the most robust way of ensuring that I am not just filling in random `id`'s that may not exist.

Answer (score 15):

I have improved upon HyperionX's answer and removed the static elements from it.

```
$factory->define(App\Note::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $noteable = [
        App\User::class,
        App\Complex::class,
    ]; // Add new noteables here as we make them
    $noteableType = $faker->randomElement($noteables);
    $noteable = factory($noteableType)->create();

    return [
        'noteable_type' => $noteableType,
        'noteable_id' => $noteable->id,
        ...
    ];
});
```

Basically, we pick one of the noteable classes at random, then call it's own factory to get an instance of noteable, thus we get rid of the staticness of the OP's answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using a morph map the given solutions won't work because the type won't be the same as the class name.

This will work in combination with a morph map.

Until Laravel 7

```php
$factory->define(App\Note::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $noteable = $faker->randomElement([
        App\User::class,
        App\Complex::class,
    ]);

    return [
        'noteable_id' => factory($noteable),
        'noteable_type' => array_search($noteable, Relation::$morphMap),
        ...
    ];
});
```

From Laravel 8

```
public function definition(): array
{
    /** @var class-string<\App\Models\User|\App\Models\Complex> $noteable */
    $noteable = $this->faker->randomElement([
        App\Models\User::class,
        App\Models\Complex::class,
    ]);

    return [
        'noteable_type' => array_search($noteable, Relation::$morphMap),
        'noteable_id' => $noteable::factory(),
    ];
}
```

More information about morph map could be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#custom-polymorphic-types

Comment: Excellent and concise solution that works for all use cases!

Answer (score 2):

Although a bit more static than I would like, here is my solution:

I created exactly 20 models of each class, that way I could ensure the Notes that are created don't try to link to something that may not exist, leaving a dangling Note object.

```
// NotesFactory.php
$factory->define(App\Note::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $noteable = [
        App\User::class,
        App\Complex::class,
    ];

    return [
        'noteable_id' => $faker->numberBetween(0,20),
        'noteable_type' => $faker->randomElement($noteable),
        ...
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class CandidateFactory extends Factory {
   
    protected $model = \App\Models\Candidate::class;

    public function definition() {
        $applicants = [
            Contact::class,
            Advertiser::class,
        ];
        /** @var Model $applicant */
        $applicant = Arr::random( $applicants )::factory()->create();

        return [
            'applicant_type' => $applicant->getMorphClass(),
            'applicant_id'   => $applicant->getKey(),
        ];
    }
}
```

Then

```
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function candidate_has_applicants() {
        $candidate = Candidate::factory()->create();
        $this->assertInstanceOf( Candidate::class, $candidate );

        $this->assertInstanceOf( Authenticatable::class, $candidate->applicant );
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Updated Answer**

If you don't care about controlling which morphable model is created:

```php
public function definition()
{
    return [
        'content' => $this->faker->paragraph(),
        'noteable_id' => function (array $attributes) {
            return $attributes['noteable_type']::factory();
        }),
        'noteable_type' => $this->faker->randomElement([
            Complex::factory(),
            User::factory()
        ]),
        'title' => $this->faker->sentence()
    ];
}
```

**Original answer**

I have another solution that does not imply the use of the `randomElement`, which is good by the way, but can be problematic when you need control on the morphable model that is being created. You still need to create model factories for the `Note`, `User` and `Complex` models. Then the `run` method of the `Databaseeder` class would look like this:

```php
public function run()
{
    $userNotes = Note::factory()->count(10)->for(
        User::factory(), 'noteable'
    )->create();

    $complexNotes = Note::factory()->count(10)->for(
        Complex::factory(), 'noteable'
    )->create();
}
```

There is another approach by using the factory states. You still need to define model factories for your 3 models. Additionally you define two state transformation methods in the `NoteFactory` class.

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class NoteFactory extends Factory
{
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'content' => $this->faker->paragraph(),
            'title' => $this->faker->sentence()
        ];
    }

    public function forComplex()
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'noteable_type' => Complex::class,
                'noteable_id' => Complex::factory()
            ];
        });
    }

    public function forUser()
    {
        return $this->state(function (array $attributes) {
            return [
                'noteable_type' => User::class,
                'noteable_id' => User::factory()
            ];
        });
    }
}
```

In this case the `Databaseeder` class `run` method would look like this:

```php
public function run()
{
    $userNotes = Note::factory()->count(10)->forUser()->create();

    $complexNotes = Note::factory()->count(10)->forComplex()->create();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this without temporary variables like this:

```php
$factory->define(App\Note::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'noteable_type' => $faker->randomElement([
            App\User::class,
            App\Complex::class,
        ]),
        'noteable_id' => function (array $note) {
            return factory($note['noteable_type']);
        },
        ...
    ];
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create 10 user with 10 notes then create 10 complex with 10 notes.
like this

```
public function run()
{
    factory(User::class,10)->create()->each(
        fn($user)=>
        factory(Note::class,10)
        ->create(["noteable_id"=>$user,"noteable_type"=>User::class]), 
    );
    factory(Complex::class,10)->create()->each(
        fn($complex)=>
        factory(Note::class,10)
        ->create(["noteable_id"=>$complex,"noteable_type"=>Complex::class]), 
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already created instances of the concrete Notables, perhaps via different factories, you may don't want to create any more new instances of it. In this case, you could extend [Barracuda's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51834502/6516194):

```php
$factory->define(App\Note::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $noteable = [
        User::class,
        Complex::class,
    ];

    $noteableType = $faker->randomElement($noteable);
    if ($noteableType === User::class) {
        $noteableId = User::all()->random()->id;
    } else {
        $noteableId = Complex::all()->random()->id;
    }

    return [
        'noteable_type' => $noteableType,
        'noteable_id' => $noteableId,
        ...
    ];
});
```

I realise this would require a little bit of additional overhead to maintain the if/else branches but you won't have the problem of using IDs that don't exist.

Perhaps there is also a more elegant and generic way to get the `Model::all()` based on the `Model::class`, however I am unaware of it.

Answer (score 0):

My preference is to use it this way, according to the factory structure, in new versions of Laravel.

```
$notable = $this->faker->randomElement([
    [
        'id' => User::all()->random(),
        'type' => User::class,
    ],
    [
        'id' => Complex::all()->random(),
        'type' => Complex::class,
    ]
]);

return [
    'notable_id' => $notable['id'],
    'notable_type' => $notable['type'],
    ...
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend model factory with state and pass to it related model, in state grab needed information and return merged results with default `definition()`

```
class NoteFactory extends Factory
{
    protected $model = Note::class;
    
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'title'      => $this->faker->sentence,
            'note'       => $this->faker->sentence,
            //...
        ];
    }
    
    //new method that specify related model 
    public function forModel($model)
    {
        return $this->state(function () use ($model){
            return [
                'noteable_type' => $model->getMorphClass(), //return App\Lead etc
                'noteable_id'   => $model->id,
            ];
        });
    }
}

//usage
Note::factory()
    ->forModel($lead) //created method passing instance of App\Lead object
    ->create();
```